# nodejs pdf to image conversion

Tags: node.js, pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-image.

```
 var PDFImage = require("pdf-image").PDFImage;

            var pdfImage = new PDFImage("brochure.pdf");
            pdfImage.convertPage(0).then(function (imagePath) {
                // 0-th page (first page) of the slide.pdf is available as slide-0.png 
                fs.existsSync("slide-0.png") // => true 
            },function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
```

But i am getting this error

```
 { message: 'Failed to convert page to image',
  error:
   { [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c convert 'brochure.pdf[0]' 'brochure-0.png'
   /bin/sh: 1: convert: not found
   ]
     killed: false,
     code: 127,
     signal: null,
     cmd: '/bin/sh -c convert \'brochure.pdf[0]\' \'brochure-0.png\'' },
  stdout: '',
  stderr: '/bin/sh: 1: convert: not found\n' }
```

Please help me how can i convert pdf to image using nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download ImageMagick in order to get the package working. You find see installation instructions on the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-image)

If you've already done so, there might be something gone wrong with your path configuration. Try these commands to fix that:

```
export MAGICK_HOME="opt/ImageMagick"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib
export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: i have already run this command successfully.   sudo apt-get install imagemagick ghostscript poppler-utils     @Karamell

Comment: What's the result if you run `which convert`?

Comment: If you need to set the path, you can do so by typing into the terminal (asuming mac or unix): `export MAGICK_HOME="opt/ImageMagick" && export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH" && export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib"`

Comment: Try [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177594/to-install-brews-imagemagick-and-fix-its-symlink)

Answer (score 0):

showing this type of error
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\mepan\Downloads\bg remove> npm install pdf-image

added 1 package, and audited 334 packages in 6s

19 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (5 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\mepan\Downloads\bg remove>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you have to change the package there is an npm package that converts PDF file to image file : pdf-poppler it works fine try it 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-poppler 
Best of luck